# Insert position

Tags: insert-mode

Recently insert position becomes strange.
<kbd>i</kbd> can change insert position. Sometimes insert to the left of current cursor, sometimes to the right.
Caps is not activated. VIM 8.0 1-586

Comment: Have you tried without a vimrc file (`vim -Nu NONE`) if you can't reproduce the problem without a vimrc then you should be able to fix your problem following [How do I debug my vimrc?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/1841)

Comment: @statox Yes, something is wrong with my .vimrc. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the link below. Now this issue is solved.
[Prevent escape from moving the cursor one character to the left](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Prevent_escape_from_moving_the_cursor_one_character_to_the_left)

---

1. Cursor move to the left is the default behaviour. Although it's kinda 
   annoying to me.
2. Side effect of above link is after `a` `Esc`, cursor will keep moving to the right.
3. Not sure why below two mapping will make `ctrl-a` move cursor to the right.
   `map saveses :mksession! ~/bin/vim/session/default.ses`
   `map loadses :source     ~/bin/vim/session/default.ses`

Comment: If the answer solves the issue could you validate the solution using the v green button next to the arrow voting button (two days after you post your own solution you are authorized to validate your solution). It allow the question to rest :-)